# Searching a table using a user-defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function

I'm trying to write an SQL function that given a name of a game, it will allow me to search the table of games for that particular game and returns all the info about that game.

This is the code for the Games table:

```
CREATE TABLE Games(

game_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50),
release_date VARCHAR(50),
rating VARCHAR(5),
min_age INT,
development_team_email VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Development_Teams,
release_conference INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Conferences
)
```

And here is the what I could come up with when I was trying to write the function:

```
create function SearchGames(@game_name varchar(50))

returns table
begin
declare @game 

Select (*)
From Games
where Games.name = @game_name

return @game
end
```

I'm getting a lot of syntax errors and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would argue that your decision to use development_team_email as a primary key is not a good one. I kind of question a number of your datatypes too. release_date as a varchar? rating as varchar?

Comment: Oops. release_date shouldn't be a varchar. However, rating should, because it can be PG, M, T, etc

Comment: Ahh then it is a good case where the name could stand a more descriptive name than rating. :) I thought it was rating, as in a review rating. Perhaps something like ContentRating maybe? This is of course WAY off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using a `function` for this, but rather a `stored procedure`:

```
Create Proc spSearchGames (@game_name Varchar (50))
As Begin
    Select  *
    From    Games
    Where   name = @game_name
End
Go
```

And executing it:

```
Exec spSearchGames 'YourGameName'
```

Comment: I was hoping someone would mention stored procedures. Please, how in god's sake do you decide on whether to use a function or a storied procedure? This is driving me crazy

Comment: `Functions` to me would be used for something that you intend to either transform data with or iterate over with each row.  Whereas `Stored Procedures` would be more for housing a specific query, or set of queries (e.g. a search query) to be executed simply.  You can use either/or in this case, but in my mind it makes more sense to use a proc.

Comment: Alright great. What is that "go" keyword in the end?

Comment: It's a batch separator in `SSMS` - if that's the only query you're running it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: What if I want to select more than thing (from more than one table) in the same procedure?

Comment: @Swailem95 You can, you just need to modify the query to pull the data you desire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95279/discussion-between-swailem95-and-siyual).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`inline table valued function`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214762%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) syntax and add schema:

```
create function dbo.SearchGames(@game_name varchar(50))
returns table
AS
RETURN (Select *
        From Games
        where Games.name = @game_name);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f702/1/0)**</kbd>

If you use stored procedure you need to use:

```
 CREATE TABLE ...;
 INSERT INTO ... EXEC stored_procedure @args;
 -- another operation on stored procedure resultset
```

while with inline table function you just:

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchGames('aaa') GROUP BY ... HAVING ... ORDER BY;
```

Comment: Why did you add "dbo." before the function name?

Comment: Because function should have schema provided

Comment: I would go a step further and suggest that you should always use the schema when creating or referencing objects. It really isn't limited to functions. :)